# Android kiosk mode app - running status bar

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I've got a problem with status bar in kiosk mode App.

I want to know **how to hide status bar** and I know that **is it possible to disable it permanently in 4.4.2 Kitkat?** But I found nice app -KioWare.

There is cool mode when I grab status bar down, it is running back to the top very quickly. In 0.05 sec. I am not able to click anything. And this is what I'm looking for.

I can't buy this app because it's to expensive and I only need this magic trick with status bar. Anyone can help me ? It should be only few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article that covers this question, but specifically for Lollipop. I'm not sure if the immersive mode in Android 5 will also apply for 4.4.2, but it's something to try out maybe?

http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    hideSystemUI();
}

// This snippet hides the system bars.
private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
    // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```